# How to create an interface composed of other interfaces?

Tags: php, interface

I'd like to create an interface, `IFoo`, that's basically a combination of a custom interface, `IBar`, and a few native interfaces, `ArrayAccess`, `IteratorAggregate`, and `Serializable`.  PHP doesn't seem to allow interfaces that implement other interfaces, as I get the following error when I try:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_IMPLEMENTS, expecting '{' in X on line Y

I know that interfaces can extend other ones, but PHP doesn't allow multiple inheritance and I can't modify native interfaces, so now I'm stuck.

Do I have to duplicate the other interfaces within `IFoo`, or is there a better way that allows me to reuse the native ones?

Comment: You have not posted any code that error relates to. But you should.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

You are looking for the `extends` keyword:

```
Interface Foo extends Bar, ArrayAccess, IteratorAggregate, Serializable
{
    ...
}
```

See [Object Interfaces](http://php.net/language.oop5.interfaces) and in specific [Example #2 Extendable Interfaces ff](http://php.net/language.oop5.interfaces#language.oop5.interfaces.examples.ex2).

---

Note: Just removed the `I` prefix in the `IFoo`, `IBar` interface names.

For an additional perspective of a PHP developer I can recommend the reading of [*"Prefixes and Suffixes Do Not Belong in Interface Names"*](https://blog.nette.org/en/prefixes-and-suffixes-do-not-belong-in-interface-names) by [David Grudl](https://davidgrudl.com/) for [Nette](https://nette.org/en/) (Jun 2022).

Comment: @Neal please visit http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php and find Example #3 Multiple interface inheritance

Comment: Extending multiple interfaces is allowed. It just fails if the same method is declared in two or more of them.

Comment: @joequincy: In which PHP version? Not in the current stable PHP release. extending from the *same* interface *multiple* times is an error condition however (which makes sense).

Comment: Eh. It's likely I'm just out of date.

Comment: Wow, thank you for teaching me to RTFM.  I just assumed that since you can't extend multiple classes with class inheritance that you also can't with interface inheritance.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use the `extends` keyword to extend your interface and when you need to implement the interface in your class then you need to use the `implements` keyword to implement it.

You can use `implements` over multiple interfaces in you class. If you implement the interface then you need to define the body of all functions, like this...

```php
interface FirstInterface
{
    function firstInterfaceMethod1();
    function firstInterfaceMethod2();
}
interface SecondInterface
{
    function SecondInterfaceMethod1();
    function SecondInterfaceMethod2();
}
interface PerantInterface extends FirstInterface, SecondInterface
{
    function perantInterfaceMethod1();
    function perantInterfaceMethod2();
}


class Home implements PerantInterface
{
    function firstInterfaceMethod1()
    {
        echo "firstInterfaceMethod1 implement";
    }

    function firstInterfaceMethod2()
    {
        echo "firstInterfaceMethod2 implement";
    }
    function SecondInterfaceMethod1()
    {
        echo "SecondInterfaceMethod1 implement";
    }
    function SecondInterfaceMethod2()
    {
        echo "SecondInterfaceMethod2 implement";
    }
    function perantInterfaceMethod1()
    {
        echo "perantInterfaceMethod1 implement";
    }
    function perantInterfaceMethod2()
    {
        echo "perantInterfaceMethod2 implement";
    }
}

$obj = new Home();
$obj->firstInterfaceMethod1();
```

and so on... call methods

Comment: Please avoid posting duplicated answers. You should have a good reason for posting an answer 6 years later.